# What's exact diff between `=` and `^~` Nginx modifiers?

Tags: nginx

As far as I've read/understood, both `=` and `^~` are normal string prefix modifier (*neither is* 'reg-exp' modifiers). Both allow only exact matches (otherwise its considered a non-match). And if exact match is found, both stop further matching process and accompanied 'location' is served right away.

Then what's the difference between these 2 modifiers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> As far as I've read/understood, both = and ^~ are normal string prefix modifier (neither is 'reg-exp' modifiers).

- `=` is exact matching, and not prefix matching at all
- `^~` is a "prioritized" prefix matching that has priority over regular expression matches. In other words, it's the same as standard prefix location like `location /something` with the only difference that if it matches the URI, then regular expression locations won't be searched.

> Both allow only exact matches (otherwise it's considered a non-match).

- `=` allows only exact matching, `location = /foo` is considered a match only for URI `/foo` (or `/foo?some=arg`) and none else, e.g. `foobar` won't match it
- `^~` allows prefix matching, e.g. `location ^~ /foo` matches `/foo` and `/foobar` and `/fooanything`

> And if exact match is found, both stop further matching process and accompanied 'location' is served right away.

> Then what's the difference between these 2 modifiers?

As outlined above, only `=` is exact matching, has only one URI base to match against, and has priority over other matching types.

The `^~` has unlimited possible matches. That is the key difference between the two.

The exact matching (`=`) is [the most performance-efficient matching type](https://www.getpagespeed.com/server-setup/nginx-locations-performance-impact-and-optimizations). Use it where possible:

```
location = /foo/bar/ { return 301 /foo; }
```

Is preferred over `location ~ ^/foo/bar$ { return 301 /foo; }`.

If you want to deny access to specific directories, prioritized prefix matching makes much sense also as it doesn't involve regular expression evaluation:

```
location ^~ /foo/ {
    deny all;
}
```

Will deny anything within `/foo/` directory, not just `/foo/` URI.

To recap:

```
# matching URIs: /foo, /foo?some=1, etc.
# fastest matching of all, highest priority
location = /foo { ... }

# matching URIs: /foo, /foob, /foob?some=1, /foobar, /foo[...]
# second fasted matching of all, the second highest priority
location ^~ /foo { ...}
```

Comment: You nailed it very good. Very good. Cleared all my doubts, removed all hindering smoke. Thank you very much.

Comment: `"Will deny anything within /foo/ directory, not just /foo/ URI."` Can you pls clear this one last sentence of yours (may be xplain with a bit of example)?

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE**

Thanks to @danila-vershinin pointing this out, but `=` actually do not define a prefix but only an exact match. See his answer for a more complete/correct answer.

**Original Answer below**

If you have a single location, then you are right, it doesn't matter whether you use `=` or `^~`. The difference comes when you have many locations, and the different modifiers affect the order for which one will match at the end.

From the [documentation](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/web-server/#nginx-location-priority):

> Higher priority is given to regular expressions, unless the `^~` modifier is used. Among the prefix strings NGINX Plus selects the most specific one (that is, the longest and most complete string). The exact logic for selecting a location to process a request is given below:
>
> 1. Test the URI against all prefix strings.
> 2. The `=` (equals sign) modifier defines an exact match of the URI and a prefix string. If the exact match is found, the search stops.
> 3. If the `^~` (caret-tilde) modifier prepends the longest matching prefix string, the regular expressions are not checked.
> 4. Store the longest matching prefix string.
> 5. Test the URI against regular expressions.
> 6. Stop processing when the first matching regular expression is found and use the corresponding location.
> 7. If no regular expression matches, use the location corresponding to the stored prefix string.

Basically, having an `= /test` is useful if you want to match the exact path `/test` and in that case all further processing (regular expressions) is omitted.

If no exact match is found, both `=` and `^~` are **prefix** matches, and the longest match from all these locations is selected. If that has the modifier `^~` it will be immediately used, otherwise the regular expressions will be checked first.

In the concrete example, if you have a location `= /test` and asking for the path `/test/bla.html`, first all other regular expressions will be checked, and only if none matches will the `= /test` be used. If instead you have `^~ /test` and ask for `/test/bla.html`, this will be used, even if there are e.g. regular expressions matching `*.html`.

**PS**

Notice that only the **longest** matching prefix is important here. If you have two locations: `= /test` and `^~ /test/bla` and asking for `/test/bla/x.html`, then the `^~ /test/bla` is the used one, and since it has `^~`, no regex will be checked. If instead the locations were `^~ /test` and `= /test/bla`, the `=` is the longest one, so regex will be checked in this case (and the `^~ /test` is completely ignored).

Comment: "If no exact match is found, both = and ^~ are prefix matches, and the longest match from all these locations is selected" that's just wrong. If a URI doesn't match the `=` matching exactly, there's no match and this location is never selected. It is not a prefix matching.

Comment: Thank you for the correction! This is interesting, I did some tests and indeed can verify you are correct. But can you explain the meaning of this sentence from point 2 from the documentation: "The = (equals sign) modifier defines an exact match of the URI and a prefix string"? Possibly the OP was confused by this same sentence in the documentation?

Comment: It sounds like bad wording in the nginx.com documentation. They seem to refer to the any string in `location` directory argument as "prefix string". Note that nginx.com belongs to mostly the commercial division and I believe it may be written by different people than the [actual official documentation of `location` directive](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) at nginx.org.

Comment: Its indeed very very confusing to a 51 year old guy like me. I try to understand this confusion by reading these answers and comments again and again, but still it's not as clear as I want it to be. But still you've done much. And I'm thankful. But if you ever find some article over these 2-3 symbols, with ample examples. I'd be obliged if you could share that here.